# Is there a script that will detect if the SSIS component is installed and running on a server?

Tags: t-sql, ssis, ssis-2012

I am building SSIS packages in SQL Server 2012 that need to be set up and applied at client sites where they will run in nightly jobs.  I do not have control over the client server machines and do not know who will be running the scripts.

But before the SSIS packages can be installed, I first need to verify using a script whether or not the SSIS component is installed and the service is running?  I know how to accomplish this task easily enough in SQL Server Configuration Manager, but I need to script this so that if SSIS is either not running or the component not installed, the user running the script is prompted early in the process.  Otherwise, it proceeds with setting up the dtsx files, permissions to run them in a job and so forth.  This script will be running at about 50 different sites where SSIS packages need to be pushed.

I've checked the master.dbo.sysprocesses table but it only shows information about processes in database engine.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942177/en-us?ppud=4&wa=wsignin1.0) is rather old, but might provide some clues. Or [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=184825) somewhat newer page.

Comment: Are you using the package deployment model or the project deployment model? Do you need to check whether 2012 itself is installed or do you have to support multiple versions?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  No I have not tried either of the two models, but have since read up on them and will be putting them to use.  This is exactly what I'm seeking.  Thanks.